# PCF DEV Network Issue - Unable to start it

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf, pcfdev

We are facing the below issue when we are able to start the PCF DEV network.

Could anyone please help on it?

[image]

C:\Users\Administrator>cf dev start -f C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pcfdev-v1.2.0-windows.tgz
FAILED
cf dev start: stopping cfdev: cf dev stop: failed to stop the VM: failed to stop vpnkit: Failed to execute C:\Users\Administrator.cfdev\winservice\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe, [C:\Users\Administrator.cfdev\winservice\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe uninstall]: exec: "C:\Users\Administrator\.cfdev\winservice\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe": file does not exist:

Comment: Please copy and paste your error into the question, linking to an image on an external site just makes it more difficult to help, especially if the image is condensed

Comment: Hi Davies,
C:\Users\Administrator>cf dev start -f C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\pcfdev-v1.2.0-windows.tgz
FAILED
cf dev start: stopping cfdev: cf dev stop: failed to stop the VM: failed to stop vpnkit: Failed to execute C:\Users\Administrator\.cfdev\winservice\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe, [C:\Users\Administrator\.cfdev\winservice\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe uninstall]: exec: "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.cfdev\\winservice\\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit\\org.cloudfoundry.cfdev.vpnkit.exe": file does not exist: